# How do I create a dashboard layout (or apply a dashboard commercial template) on a project from angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've just created a new Angular 2 project using @angular/cli, then I installed Admin LTE using `npm install admin-lte --save` as usual, to create the layout like the image bellow.

I've replaced the content of app/index.html from this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

by this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/admin-lte/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. We have chosen the skin-blue for this starter
          page. However, you can choose any other skin. Make sure you
          apply the skin class to the body tag so the changes take effect.
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Main Header -->
    <header class="main-header">

        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="index2.html" class="logo">
            <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
            <span class="logo-mini"><b>A</b>LT</span>
            <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
            <span class="logo-lg"><b>Admin</b>LTE</span>
        </a>

        <!-- Header Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
            <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            </a>
            <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
            <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
                    <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
                        <!-- Menu toggle button -->
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                            <span class="label label-success">4</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="header">You have 4 messages</li>
                            <li>
                                <!-- inner menu: contains the messages -->
                                <ul class="menu">
                                    <li><!-- start message -->
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="pull-left">
                                                <!-- User Image -->
                                                <img src="admin-lte/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
                                            <h4>
                                                Support Team
                                                <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 mins</small>
                                            </h4>
                                            <!-- The message -->
                                            <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <!-- end message -->
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.menu -->
                            </li>
                            <li class="footer"><a href="#">See All Messages</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- /.messages-menu -->

                    <!-- Notifications Menu -->
                    <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
                        <!-- Menu toggle button -->
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
                            <span class="label label-warning">10</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="header">You have 10 notifications</li>
                            <li>
                                <!-- Inner Menu: contains the notifications -->
                                <ul class="menu">
                                    <li><!-- start notification -->
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> 5 new members joined today
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <!-- end notification -->
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="footer"><a href="#">View all</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Tasks Menu -->
                    <li class="dropdown tasks-menu">
                        <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="fa fa-flag-o"></i>
                            <span class="label label-danger">9</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="header">You have 9 tasks</li>
                            <li>
                                <!-- Inner menu: contains the tasks -->
                                <ul class="menu">
                                    <li><!-- Task item -->
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <!-- Task title and progress text -->
                                            <h3>
                                                Design some buttons
                                                <small class="pull-right">20%</small>
                                            </h3>
                                            <!-- The progress bar -->
                                            <div class="progress xs">
                                                <!-- Change the css width attribute to simulate progress -->
                                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" style="width: 20%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                                    <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <!-- end task item -->
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="footer">
                                <a href="#">View all tasks</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- User Account Menu -->
                    <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                        <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <!-- The user image in the navbar-->
                            <img src="admin-lte/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
                            <!-- hidden-xs hides the username on small devices so only the image appears. -->
                            <span class="hidden-xs">Alexander Pierce</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <!-- The user image in the menu -->
                            <li class="user-header">
                                <img src="admin-lte/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

                                <p>
                                    Alexander Pierce - Web Developer
                                    <small>Member since Nov. 2012</small>
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Menu Body -->
                            <li class="user-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                        <a href="#">Followers</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                        <a href="#">Sales</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                        <a href="#">Friends</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.row -->
                            </li>
                            <!-- Menu Footer-->
                            <li class="user-footer">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
    <aside class="main-sidebar">

        <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <section class="sidebar">

            <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
            <div class="user-panel">
                <div class="pull-left image">
                    <img src="admin-lte/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                </div>
                <div class="pull-left info">
                    <p>Alexander Pierce</p>
                    <!-- Status -->
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- search form (Optional) -->
            <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- /.search form -->

            <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
            <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                <li class="header">HEADER</li>
                <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Link</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Another Link</span></a></li>
                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Multilevel</span>
                        <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
        </section>
        <!-- /.sidebar -->
    </aside>

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
                Page Header
                <small>Optional description</small>
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Level</a></li>
                <li class="active">Here</li>
            </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">

            <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>

        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

    <!-- Main Footer -->
    <footer class="main-footer">
        <!-- To the right -->
        <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
            Anything you want
        </div>
        <!-- Default to the left -->
        <strong>Copyright &copy; 2016 <a href="#">Company</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
    </footer>

    <!-- Control Sidebar -->
    <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
        <!-- Create the tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified control-sidebar-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#control-sidebar-home-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#control-sidebar-settings-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <!-- Home tab content -->
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="control-sidebar-home-tab">
                <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Recent Activity</h3>
                <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-birthday-cake bg-red"></i>

                            <div class="menu-info">
                                <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Langdon's Birthday</h4>

                                <p>Will be 23 on April 24th</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

                <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Tasks Progress</h3>
                <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                                Custom Template Design
                                <span class="pull-right-container">
                  <span class="label label-danger pull-right">70%</span>
                </span>
                            </h4>

                            <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 70%"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.tab-pane -->
            <!-- Stats tab content -->
            <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-stats-tab">Stats Tab Content</div>
            <!-- /.tab-pane -->
            <!-- Settings tab content -->
            <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-settings-tab">
                <form method="post">
                    <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">General Settings</h3>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                            Report panel usage
                            <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
                        </label>

                        <p>
                            Some information about this general settings option
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.form-group -->
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- /.tab-pane -->
        </div>
    </aside>
    <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
    <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
         immediately after the control sidebar -->
    <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->

<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="admin-lte/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="admin-lte/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="admin-lte/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>

<!-- Optionally, you can add Slimscroll and FastClick plugins.
     Both of these plugins are recommended to enhance the
     user experience. Slimscroll is required when using the
     fixed layout. -->
</body>
</html>
```

But it didn't find any of the styles and scripts. What do I have to do?

### UPDATE

To clarify my question, I'm adding an image of a common dashboard structure.

My questions are (including the previous one from the original question):

- Do I need to have a main component (like AppComponent) to show everything inside of it? Or can I have multiple components and its tags defined in the index.html?
- Do I have to create a component for each section (Sidebar, Header, Content area)?
- How do I handle the replacement of the content area when a link is clicked?

[image]

Comment: You can use this [**lib**](https://github.com/TwanoO67/ng2-admin-lte).

Comment: Thank you, but AdminLTE is just an example for my current "experiment". I 
 want to learn how can I do this manually with any template I buy or build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do I need to have a main component (like AppComponent) to show everything inside of it? Or can I have multiple components and its tags defined in the index.html?**

You need to think of these parts of your page as components. When you are going to do it in the frameworks/libraries like Angular, React or Vue, all of the HTML generation becomes responsibility of framework. So your HTML will have bare minimum markup and load all the basic stuff; just like you mentioned in the first code sample.

Now in the code, where you have app-root, it will have the underlying structure in its template. like:

```
<app-header />
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <app-sidebar />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <app-container />
  </div>
</div>
<app-footer />
```

all the `app-*` tags become component in themselves. Main idea is to think in components

**Do I have to create a component for each section (Sidebar, Header, Content area)?**

Yes as explained in the above section of the answer, you would have to create the components for each one of them. Rather components of smallest reusable block as well so that you can configure your UI very easily.

**How do I handle the replacement of the content area when a link is clicked?**

This is your app logic. There can be many way to handle that. On way is to have conditions in the template. Like in following code example (take from documentation site https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-if-then-else',
  template: `
    <button (click)="show = !show">{{show ? 'hide' : 'show'}}</button>
    <button (click)="switchPrimary()">Switch Primary</button>
    show = {{show}}
    <br>
    <div *ngIf="show; then thenBlock; else elseBlock">this is ignored</div>
    <ng-template #primaryBlock>Primary text to show</ng-template>
    <ng-template #secondaryBlock>Secondary text to show</ng-template>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>Alternate text while primary text is hidden</ng-template>
`
})
class NgIfThenElse implements OnInit {
  thenBlock: TemplateRef<any> = null;
  show: boolean = true;
  @ViewChild('primaryBlock')
  primaryBlock: TemplateRef<any> = null;
  @ViewChild('secondaryBlock')
  secondaryBlock: TemplateRef<any> = null;
  switchPrimary() {
    this.thenBlock = this.thenBlock === this.primaryBlock ? this.secondaryBlock : this.primaryBlock;
  }
  ngOnInit() { this.thenBlock = this.primaryBlock; }
}
```

This way you can show/hide replace some conditional content.

Though when you go forward and want to have pages in app, you would need to use router. This will handle replacing of content on the basis of URL. and based on what URL looks like, you can define what component to be loaded in the router's placeholder. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html.